# User details not shown in 'git config' command

Tags: git

I run '`git config --list`' command, but list doesn't contain user name and user mail-id.

'`git config user.name`' too returns nothing.

Comment: Can you check in git-config file? open the file in your home directory (~/.gitconfig)

Comment: Yes, and what? What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then simply define that with:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config user.name myName
git config user.email myEmail
```

Or, if you want to define that for *all* repositories:

```
git config --global user.name myName
git config --global user.email myEmail
```